# Problem to launch grid setup for oracle linux

Tags: oraclelinux

```
[oracle@oavn grid]$ ./gridSetup.sh
ERROR: Unable to verify the graphical display setup. This application requires X display. Make sure that xdpyinfo exist under PATH variable.
Can't open perl script "/u01/app/19c/grid/bin/gridSetup.pl": (null)
```

This is the error message seems like I cannot solve it.

I already try to change some of the text using `gedit` and I already make sure all has the same name and host and everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have X-Windows services running on the server. This is usually `graphical.target` (previously run level 5).

If you are using ssh to connect to the server, you will need X-Windows on your client as well. Then use `ssh -X`, `ssh -Y` or put the following in your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
    ForwardX11 yes
```

You can check the DISPLAY environment variable is set:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

And you can test by running `xclock` on the server command line, which will run the open the clock on your own monitor.

Note that this is for Unix-based (e.g. Linux) client and server. You can use Cygwin ([cygwin.com](https://cygwin.com)) on some alternative OS's.